# JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to CLLocationDegrees

Tags: ios, react-native

My react-native app is working fine in android without any problem. But when I run it in IOS simulator, this error comes to app screen and it doesn't go further:

```
JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to CLLocationDegrees 

+ RCTConvert(CoreLocation) CLLocationDegrees:] RCTConvert+CoreLocation.m:12 

+ RCTConvert(CoreLocation) CLLocationCoordinate2D:] 

+ [RCTConvert(AirMap) MKCoordinateRegion:] 

__invoking___ 

-[NSInvocation invoke] 

__41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke.80 

__41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke.164 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] 

facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) 

facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() 

const invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)

_dispatch_call_block_and_release 

_dispatch_client_callout 

_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
    
_dispatch_lane_invoke 

_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread 

_pthread_wqthread 

start_wqthread
```

Any ideas?

Comment: CLLocationDegrees is of type double - don't think it can be assigned a null value.  You may need to format it to 0, if null if returned. 

Hard to say without more information - but I assume this is the bridge code between RN and Swift.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric Do you mean formatting the simulator? Sorry but I didn't understand what you mean. I have only a little basic information about IOS native language, I didn't understand anything from this error code, and no detail is written about which file and line number.